# Google Play Published but Item Not Found

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on `google play store`, it was published more than **48** hours ago. If I am signed in to my developer email account, I could open my link to see but if it's from other phone, it says,

> ITEM NOT FOUND.

It's released on production mode and I am unsure how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you describe is the expected one when you deploy in alpha or beta channels (and your account is linked as tester), but not in production.

Just in case, check out that you have allowed the proper countries when publishing.

If you are really in production and the config is fine, the console does not show any problem and you can't see the app from any device, contact the support team then.